# Production tailwind css not displaying correctly on production

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs, digital-ocean-apps

So, I noticed some of my tailwind css is not generating properly on production but appearing well on my local any ideas ? I am using, vue + tailwind + laravel + inertia stack. Also I'm not experienced in deploying anything on production, so thus I am using digital ocean's new "Apps" thing.

**Production**

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- Node Version: 12.22.5

**Local**

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Node Version: v16.7.0

**What it's suppose to look like ( Local )**

[image]

**What it turned up like ( Production )**
[image]

**Here is my tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    // './resources/**/*.vue',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: {
          750: '#2d3748',
          850: '#1a202c'
        },
      },
      spacing: {
        112: '28rem',
        120: '30rem',
        128: '32rem',
        136: '34rem',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**Commands I run on build production**

```
Build Command
composer install --optimize-autoloader
composer dump-autoload --optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan optimize
php artisan migrate
npm install --no-optional
npm run production

php artisan ziggy:generate
```

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-white pt-12">
        <Navbar class="mb-2"/>
        <div class="flex flex-row lg:mx-40 md:mx-10">
            <div class="md:w-64 w-2/12">
                <div class="bg-gray-300 h-screen flex flex-col p-4 space-y-10">
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <b>Categories</b>
                        </span>
                        <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 cursor-pointer" v-for="category in categories">
                            <span @click="filterCategory(category)">{{ category.name }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <b>Price Range</b>
                        </span>
                        <div class="flex flex-col font-semibold">
                            Minimum Price<input type="text" name="min" placeholder="Min" v-model="filters.minPrice" class="rounded-xl px-2">
                            Maximum Price<input type="text" name="min" placeholder="Max" v-model="filters.maxPrice" class="rounded-xl px-2">
                        </div>
                        <button class="p-0.5 px-2 mt-2 bg-gray-600 text-gray-300 rounded-xl" @click="filter">Filter</button>
                        <button class="p-0.5 ml-2 px-2 mt-2  text-gray-600 rounded-xl" @click="clearPrice">Clear</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-10/12 flex flex-col">
                <div class="flex flex-row items-center pl-2">
                    Search <input v-model="filters.search" @keyup="filter" type="text" name="min" placeholder="Search Products" class="border border-gray-400 rounded-xl p-1 m-2 w-full">
                </div>
                <FilterTags :filters="filters" @remove="removeCategory"/>
                <div class="flex flex-wrap h-1/3 cursor-pointer">
                    <div v-for="product in products.data" class="w-1/5">
                        <ProductCard class="m-4" :name="product.name" :price="product.price" :currency="'RM'"  @click="viewDetails(product.id)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/Components/Shop/Navbar';
import ProductCard from '@/Components/Shop/ProductCard';
import FilterTags from '@/Components/Shop/FilterTags';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default {
    components: {
        Navbar,
        ProductCard,
        FilterTags,
    },
    props: {
        products: {
            type: Object,
            default: {}
        },
        categories: {
            type: Object,
            default: {}
        },
        filters: {
            type: Object,
            default: {}
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted () {
    },
    methods: {
        filter: debounce( function() {
            this.$inertia.get(route('playground.shop.index'), this.filters, { preserveState: true });
        }, 300),
        filterCategory: debounce( function(category) {
            this.filters.categories.push(category.name);
            this.filter();
        }, 200),
        removeCategory(removedCategory) {
            this.filters.categories = this.filters.categories.filter(function(category) {
                return category != removedCategory;
            });
            this.filter();
        },
        clearPrice() {
            this.filters.minPrice = null;
            this.filters.maxPrice = null;
            this.filter();
        },
        viewDetails(product) {
            this.$inertia.visit(route('playground.shop.product.show', product));
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to uncomment the line that prevents PostCSS from purging the Tailwind classes you're using on your Vue files.

```js
// Change this:
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    // './resources/**/*.vue',
  ]
}

// to this:
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue'
  ]
}
```

Comment: ah... okay forgot about that this thing exists... thanks i will try

Comment: @Napmi Remember that  you can run `npm run production` in your local environment, so you test the actual output, if it "fails" or is not correctly displayed, same will happen when you upload the data to a server and run the same command. Do not worry about the command having `production` in it, you can run it and see the actual result.

Comment: @matiaslauriti oh i did not know this. this is a very good tip ! thanks !

Comment: @Napmi that command should minify, uglyfy and package any file, so the size goes as down as possible, also prunes or purges any stuff it should, like dev output, or in this case, any non used CSS (your tailwind's purge). It can also version stuff if you are using `mix.version()`.

Comment: That changed for v3 from purge to content:
[link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources)